# I can't migrate table into database in laravel 5.6

Tags: database, laravel-5, migration

In laravel 5.6, when I am trying to migrate table 'todos' it shows this error:

[image: Run file image]

And this is table code:

[Table code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzSCs.png)

Comment: Please [do not post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors); please put the text of the code into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit `appServiceProvider` to this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

This is because Laravel changed their default databse character set to `utf8mb4` (supporting emojis i.e).

See the soutiuon in Laravel documentation here (under the heading: `Index Lengths & MySQL / MariaDB)`: https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#creating-indexes